# How to get all field name of field type?

Tags: 8, entities

I want get all the field names for the fields whose field type is *image*, by code. How can do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for [EntityFieldManager::getFieldMapByFieldType()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityFieldManager.php/function/EntityFieldManager%3A%3AgetFieldMapByFieldType/8.2.x):

```
\Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldMapByFieldType('image');
```